# Searching through JSON data in MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, search

The last time I have posted a question about searching [JSON data using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943843/reading-partial-json-data-with-mysql-and-php/53944072#53944072). After testing the script I wanted to try something else. Using MySQL to search through the data. Since it is faster than looping everything using a PHP script. 
I was writing the script in PhpMyAdmin and that has generated the next PHP script for me. But somewhere there is a bug (sad)

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM `bigtree_pages` 
 WHERE `resources` like \'%\"XNCatDesc\": \"%?%\' and `resources` like \'%\"Brand\": \"%?%\' and `resources` like \'%\"ItemDesc\": \"%?%\'"
```

I want to give three values. The Categorie, the brand, and the ItemDesc (the name). But this throws an error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '\'%"XNCatDesc": "%'41'%\' and `resources` like \'%"Brand":
>   "%'none'%\' and `reso'

To be honest, I don't really know where I have to put my % sign. 
For example. I have this in my JSON `"Brand": "Bullet",`
The value needs to be `Brand` (since we are searching on the Brand) and the brand is Bullet. What is the best way to write this query?

Comment: This is not something you want to do in MySQL. JSON escaping is important and not easily accommodated here. If JSON data is really important to your application and you're just getting started, consider switching to [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org) which has [advanced JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) that can do all this and more.

Answer (score 1):

To use a parameter inside a `LIKE` expression in a prepared query, you need to form the entire expression and use that as the parameter. Otherwise you run into issues as you have with the insertion of quotes into your value. If you are using `mysqli`, try something like this (assuming your connection is called `$conn` and the values you want to search for are called `$categorie`, `$brand` and `$itemdesc`):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * 
                        FROM `bigtree_pages` 
                        WHERE `resources` like ? and `resources` like ? and `resources` like ?");
$search_categorie = "%\"XNCatDesc\": \"%$categorie%\"";
$search_brand = "%\"Brand\": \"%$brand%\"";
$search_itemdesc = "%\"ItemDesc\": \"%$itemdesc%\"";
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $search_categorie, $search_brand, $search_itemdesc);
$stmt->execute();
```

However the problem you will run into is that because of the `%` surrounding the search values (e.g. `$brand`) in the query, when searching for `brand = X` you could match for example

```
"Brand": "Y", "Other Value": "contains an X"
```

So instead you should use regular expressions e.g.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * 
                        FROM `bigtree_pages` 
                        WHERE `resources` rlike ? AND `resources` rlike ? AND `resources` rlike ?");
$search_categorie = '"XNCatDesc":[[:space:]]+"[^"]*' . $categorie;
$search_brand = '"Brand":[[:space:]]+"[^"]*' . $brand;
$search_itemdesc = '"ItemDesc":[[:space:]]+"[^"]*' . $itemdesc;
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $search_categorie, $search_brand, $search_itemdesc);
$stmt->execute();
```

If you are running MySQL 5.7 or later, this is better done using the inbuilt [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) function:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * 
                        FROM `bigtree_pages` 
                        WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`resources`, '$.XNCatDesc') LIKE ? and
                              JSON_EXTRACT(`resources`, '$.Brand') LIKE ? and 
                              JSON_EXTRACT(`resources`, '$.ItemDesc') LIKE ?");
$search_categorie = "%$categorie%";
$search_brand = "%$brand%";
$search_itemdesc = "%$itemdesc%";
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $search_categorie, $search_brand, $search_itemdesc);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: This is a step up, but there's still an additional level of JSON quoting that must happen here.

Comment: @tadman I've tested this on my local server and it works as expected, what are you referring to?

Comment: That last example with `JSON_EXTRACT` solves the problem. I mean that if you're looking for the text `'like "this" text'` then you'll need to JSON quote as well.